How to remove custom suggestion from IntelliSense of Visual Studio
I have this suggestion shown and selected by default every time.

Even if I press ctrl+space on the empty line

Does anybody know how I can remove that?
It is the same for every project, so I assume it is inside of the installed VS 2022.
I wasn't able to find where it is located. E.g. nothing was found in VC#\Snippets\
UPD: Search results in the folder Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise by the keyword is


If you want to remove custom suggestions from intellisense, please open the Code Snippets Manager (Tools/Code Snippets Manager) and select the language location where you have added custom suggestion. Then check if this list contains "is {}".If so, please navigate to the location and delete the specified snippet file. You can also add and remove snippet directories with the Add and Remove buttons in the Code Snippets Manager dialog.
For example:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\xxx.snippet
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets

Hope it can help you.

Thank you!
Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find my snippet there in any language.
Even when I searched the whole enterprise folder with is keyword.
Attached the screenshot in the original question

Moreover, very interesting that this suggestion does not have any icon. I assume custom snippets would have the same icon like #if and #region

Are you able to find your snippet file in this folder "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Code Snippets"?

From looking at your screenshot Results in Enterprise , i don't see file suffix .snippet. What is the path of your enterprise folder you searched?

Enterprise folder is "%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise" (Wanted to check snippets folders for all languages (VB, VC#, etc.))
Didn't find anything useful here "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Code Snippets", only a couple of snippets am aware of

Hi Viacheslav, try to search is snippet file in your C drive and it will cost some time. If still not found, did you install any intellisense extensions that may birng this suggestion?

Searching by *is*.snippet didn't show anything interesting. Even a quick search through all the files containing is did not reveal anything that caught my eye. I believe I do not have an extension which could bring that "suggestion". But some time ago I tried a bunch of different extensions that could do this, for example ReSharper. If my memory doesn't play tricks on me, I think this "suggestion" was added by me a long time ago while writing code in Visual Studio, perhaps even in a previous version of Visual Studio.

Open Extensions->Resharper->Options and select "Visual Studio " to use VS native intellisense to see if "is" appears. How many instances of VS installed in your machine now? Do you remember whether you followed this doc to add custom suggestions?

Currently I do not have Resharper installed, so there is no such options. Currently I have only one instance of VS 2022. I do not remember creating snippet that way. I am not sure but I think I added it while writing code in VS by pressing some combination of buttons or/and with context menu.

The last recommended way is to uninstall and reinstall your VS if you want. Uninstallation  may remove all  IntelliSense related files.

Thank you! I'll probably wait until it drives me completely crazy, and only then will I try to reinstall.

If you decide to uninstall VS later/in the future and it works, feel free to let us know.
